# VB Label Text issue

Tags: vb.net

In a piece of code I am writing I am trying to change the text of a label in my form based on a timer. I have MANY other labels that are all updating in their own subs and when I try to add any new labels(in any sub) to update it wont.

I am using Label.Text = counter

where counter is a string that is changing. I have tried refreshing the form, Label.refresh() Label1.Update()....The only thing I think it could be is that the redraw is being held up by other calculations on the cpu.

How can I make the label text change and update properly?

Comment: How many is MANY. and are you using vb or vb.net

Comment: at least 15 other labels that are updating properly, and VB.net

Answer (score 1):

Try putting "DoEvents" in the loop. In VB.Net, it's `Application.DoEvents()`. In VB6, it's just `DoEvents`.

Some people consider DoEvents bad form and recommend background threads to handle situations like this. To handle it this way, you can put the loop into a BackgroundWorker (vb.net) and then you should be able to update labels.

Comment: I say DoEvents is fine.  Even Microsoft recommends it if multhithreading your application will cause you many headaches.

Comment: processes all messages that are currently waiting in the message queue.